# Docker container pulled with singularity 2.5.2 works with 3.1.1 exec, but fails if I pull with 3.1.1

Tags: singularity-container, dockstore

If I pull a docker image with singularity 2.5.2 it runs fine with the 3.1.1 exec:

```sh
$ /software/singularity-3.1.1/bin/singularity exec dockstore-cgpwxs_singularity_bug_report_pull_2.5.2.simg samtools view

Usage: samtools view [options] <in.bam>|<in.sam>|<in.cram> [region ...]
...
```

If I then pull the same image with 3.1.1 and attempt to run it I get problems loading shared libraries, these are ones being used within the container (not by singularity itself as in #3027):

```sh
$ /software/singularity-3.1.1/bin/singularity exec dockstore-cgpwxs_singularity_bug_report_pull_3.1.1.simg samtools view
samtools: error while loading shared libraries: libhts.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

On the container pulled with 3.1.1 I've checked the files indicated as being a problem:

```sh
$ /software/singularity-3.1.1/bin/singularity exec dockstore-cgpwxs_singularity_bug_report_pull_3.1.1.simg ls -l /opt/wtsi-cgp/lib/
total 8613
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  415532 Apr 16 10:33 libBigWig.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  240712 Apr 16 10:33 libBigWig.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4950682 Apr 16 10:33 libhts.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      13 Apr 16 10:33 libhts.so -> libhts.so.1.9
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3211128 Apr 16 10:33 libhts.so.1.9
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      13 Apr 16 10:33 libhts.so.2 -> libhts.so.1.9
drwxrwxr-x 63 root root    1186 Apr 16 07:31 perl5
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root      32 Apr 15 08:08 pkgconfig
```

This is an exact match to the same folder when pulled with 2.5.2.

I'd expect the image pulled with 3.1.1 and executed with 3.1.1 to function better than one pulled with 2.5.2.

Linked [GitHub issue](https://github.com/sylabs/singularity/issues/3331)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been tagged as a regression by the Singularity developers.  Although not resolved yet this confirms this isn't a usage error.